# A question about asymptotic affinity and strict convexity with unbounded means

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, asymptotics, convexity, limits-and-convergence

Let $F:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a $C^1$ strictly convex function.

Let $\lambda_n \in [0,1],a_n\le c<b_n \in [0,\infty)$ satisfy
$$ \lambda_n a_n +(1-\lambda_n)b_n=c_n \tag{1}$$ and assume that
$c_n \to ֿ\infty$. (which implies $b_n \to ֿ\infty$). $c>0$ is just some constant, to make $a_n$ bounded.

Set $D_n=\lambda_nF(a_n)+(1-\lambda_n)F(b_n)-F\big(c_n\big) $, and assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty}D_n=0$

> **Question:** Does $\lambda_n \to 0$?

My intuition is that even if $F$ becomes "less convex" (closer to being affine) when $x \to \infty$, then we cannot put to much weight on the $a_n$-since otherwise we get hit by the "convexity gap" between $a_n$ and $b_n$ by a non-negligible amount, which should make $D_n$ large.

**Edit:**

This is an attempt to understand Ron P's answer:

We have
$D(a_n,c_n,b_n)=\lambda_n F(a_n)+(1-\lambda_n)F( b_n)-F(c_n)$, where $ \lambda_n a_n +(1-\lambda_n) b_n=c_n$.

Similarly,
$D(a,c_n,b_n)=\tilde \lambda_n F(a)+(1-\tilde \lambda_n)F( b_n)-F(c_n)$, where $ \tilde\lambda_n a +(1-\tilde \lambda_n) b_n=\tilde c_n$.

Suppose that $a_n \to a$. (This implies $\lambda_n-\tilde \lambda_n \to 0$). We have

$$D(a_n,c_n,b_n)-D(a,c_n,b_n)=\lambda_n F(a_n)-\tilde \lambda_n F(a)+(\tilde \lambda_n-\lambda_n)F(b_n). \tag{2}$$ The first term tends to zero, since $F(a_n) \to F(a)$ and $\lambda_n-\tilde \lambda_n \to 0$.

Why does the second term tend to zero? we don't have control over $F(b_n)$, right?

Comment: It should be  easy to make a strictly convex function with $F(2n)/2+F(0)/2 -F(n)=1/n$,  as envelope of a family of lines.  (that is a counterexample with $a_n=0, c_n=n, b_n=2n, \lambda_n=1/2$)

Comment: One can also just do it for powers of 2, b_n=2^n

Comment: Dear Pietro, it seems that your suggestion cannot work. You may see Iosif Pinelis's answer below which proves that the answer is in fact positive.

Comment: Yes! I realized it with the tentative counterexample in the answer then deleted. The fact it does not work may be turned into a positive proof

Comment: Is assumed that $F$ is increasing?

Comment: @RonP No, I don't assume that, why? Do you have a simpler proof for the case where $F$ is increasing?

Comment: @AsafShachar. Got it. See another proof below. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Indeed, by rescaling, without loss of generality (wlog) $c=1$. To simplify the notations, let $f:=F$, $a:=a_n$, $b:=b_n$, $c:=c_n$, $t:=\lambda_n$, $D:=D_n$. Passing to a subsequence, wlog $a\to a_*\in[0,1]$ and $t\to t_*\in(0,1]$. Also, wlog $a+2\le c$, since $a\le1$ and $c\to\infty$. Also, wlog $b>c$, since wlog $t>0$ and $c>a$.

By the convexity of $f$ and inequalities $a+1\le a+2\le c$,
\begin{equation*}
    f(a+1)\ge f(c)+\frac{a+1-c}{b-c}\,(f(b)-f(c)).\tag{1} 
\end{equation*}
Using now the convexity of $f$ again together with the inequality $a+2\le c$ and (1), we have
\begin{align*}
    0\le d&:=\frac{f(a)+f(a+2)}2-f(a+1) \\
    &\le \frac{f(a)}2+\frac12\,\frac{(c-a-2)f(a)+2f(c)}{c-a}-f(a+1) \\ 
    &=\tilde d:=\frac{(c-a-1)f(a)+f(c)}{c-a}-f(a+1) \\ 
    &\le\frac{(c-a-1)f(a)+f(c)+D}{c-a} \\
    &\ \ -\Big(f(c)+\frac{a+1-c}{b-c}\,(f(b)-f(c))\Big) \\
    &=\tilde D:=\frac{b-a-1}{b-a}\frac Dt\sim\frac D{t_*}\to0, 
\end{align*}
so that
\begin{equation*}
    d\to0. \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
On the other hand,
\begin{equation*}
    d\to\frac{f(a_*)+f(a_*+2)}2-f(a_*+1)>0
\end{equation*}
by the strict convexity of $f$. This contradicts (2). $\Box$

*Remark:* As seen from the above, condition $c\to\infty$ can be relaxed to $\liminf(c-a)>0$.

---

The above solution might look somewhat mysterious. In fact, the idea is a rather simple geometric one. For any real $A,B,C$ such as $A\le B\le C$, let the "gain" $g(A,B;C)$ denote the distance between the point on the graph of the convex function $f$ with abscissa $C$ and the point with the same abscissa on the chord connecting the points on the graph of $f$ with abscissas $A$ and $B$.

So (see the picture below), $D=g(a,b;c)$ and $\tilde d=g(a,c;a+1)$, where $\tilde d$ is as defined in the above multi-line display. In that display, it was shown that $\tilde d\le\tilde D$, which is clear from the picture. Also, if $t$ is bounded away from $0$ -- that is, if $c/b$ is bounded away from $1$, then, as it is clear from the picture by looking at the similar triangles, we have $\tilde D\asymp D\to0$; cf. the last line of the above multi-line display. This and the inequality $\tilde d\le\tilde D$ imply $\tilde d\to0$.

By the convexity of $f$, for any fixed real $A,C$ such as $A\le C$, the gain $g(A,B;C)$ is nondecreasing in $B\in[C,\infty)$ (here you may want to draw another picture). Therefore and because $a+2\le c$, we have $d=g(a,a+2;a+1)\le g(a,c;a+1)=\tilde d$, so that $d\le\tilde d$, which was shown in the first three lines of the above multi-line display.

This is the geometric explanation of (1) and the above multi-line display.

[image]

Comment: wow! This is an amazing answer, really. I liked a lot your geometric explanation and picture-very clear. (and indeed it was a bit mysterious before you added them). Just to be sure- in your third (last) inequality you have added the non-negative term $\frac{D}{c-a}$? I am also not sure how did you deduce that this was the "right thing" to add in order to get $\tilde D$. Did you also use the visual intuition from the picture here, or did you just take the difference and then wrote it "backwards"?

Answer (score 2):

First let's reformulate the question. For $0\leq a\leq c\leq b$, let $\lambda=\lambda(a,c,b)\in[0,1]$ be the number such that $c=\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b$, and for $f\colon \mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R$ define
$$
D_f(a,c,b)= \lambda f(a)+(1-\lambda)f(b)-f(c).
$$

> **Lemma 1.** Let $f\colon \mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R$ be strictly convex and continuously differentiable. Let $0\leq a_n\leq c_n\leq b_n$ be sequences such that $a_n$ is bounded, $c_n-a_n$ is bounded away from 0, and $\limsup \lambda(a_n,c_n,b_n)>0$. Then, $\limsup D_f(a_n,c_n,b_n)>0$.

We first apply a sequence of reduction steps that allow us to assume wlog that $a_n=0$, $c_n\geq 1$, , for all $n$, and $\liminf\lambda(a_n,c_n,b_n)>0$. If you trust that that is possible, you may skip directly to Lemma 5 below.

By taking a sub-sequence $n'$ on which $\liminf \lambda(a_{n'},c_{n'},b_{n'})>0$, Lemma 1 follows from Lemma 2.

> **Lemma 2.** Let $f\colon \mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R$ be strictly convex and continuously differentiable. Let $0\leq a_n\leq c_n\leq b_n$ be sequences such that $a_n$ is bounded, $c_n-a_n$ is bounded away from 0, and $\liminf \lambda(a_n,c_n,b_n)>0$. Then, $\limsup D_f(a_n,c_n,b_n)>0$.

By further taking a sub-sequence $n'$ on which both $a_{n'}$ converges, Lemma 2 follows from Lemma 3.

> **Lemma 3.** Let $f\colon \mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R$ be strictly convex and continuously differentiable. Let $0\leq a_n\leq c_n\leq b_n$ be sequences such that $a_n\to a$, $c_n-a_n$ is bounded away from 0, and $\liminf \lambda(a_n,c_n,b_n)>0$. Then, $\limsup D_f(a_n,c_n,b_n)>0$.

For any fixed $\epsilon>0$, the functions $\lambda(a,c,b)$ is continuous in $a$ uniformly in $c$ and $b$ over the domain $\epsilon\leq a +\epsilon\leq c\leq b$; therefore, under the assumptions of Lemma 3, $0<\liminf\lambda(a_n,c_n,b_n)=\liminf\lambda(\lim a_n,c_n,b_n)$. Furthermore, for $\lim a_n <a<\liminf c_n$ small enough, we have $\liminf\lambda(a,c_n,b_n)>0$. Since $D_f(a,c,b)$ is decreasing in $a$, $\limsup D_f(a_n,c_n,b_n)\geq\limsup D_f(a,c_n,b_n)$.
Therefore, Lemma 3 follows from Lemma 4.

> **Lemma 4.** Let $f\colon \mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R$ be strictly convex and continuously differentiable. Let $0\leq a\leq c_n\leq b_n$ be sequences such that  $c_n-a$ is bounded away from 0, and $\liminf \lambda(a,c_n,b_n)>0$. Then, $\limsup D_f(a,c_n,b_n)>0$.

Let $T\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be the affine transformation that maps $a$ to $0$ and $\inf c_n$ to $1$. Replacing $f$ by $F=f\circ T^{-1}$, and $a,c_n,b_n$ by $T(a),T(c_n),T(b_n)$ respectively, Lemma 4 follows from Lemma 5.

> **Lemma 5.** Let $F\colon \mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R$ be strictly convex and continuously differentiable. Let $1\leq c_n\leq b_n$ be sequences such that $\liminf \lambda(0,c_n,b_n)>0$. Then, $\limsup D_F(0,c_n,b_n)>0$.

**Proof of Lemma 5.**
We assume wlog that $F(0)=0$ and denote $\lambda_n=\lambda(0,c_n,b_n)$ and $D_n=D_F(0,c_n,b_n)$.

Define a function $G\colon [1,\infty)\times (1,\infty)\to \mathbb R$ by
$$
G(x,y)=\tfrac 1 y F(xy)-F(x).
$$

> **Claim 6.** $G$ is positive and increasing in both $x$ and $y$.

**Proof of Claim 6.**
Since $F$ is strictly convex, $F(0)=0$,  and $x = 1/y(xy)+(1-1/y)0$, $G(xy)>0$. Since $F'$ is increasing, we have $\frac {d}{dx}G(xy)=F'(xy)-F'(x)>0$, so $G$ increases in $x$. Since $F'$ is increasing and $G(x,y)=1/y\int_0^yF'(xt)x\,dt - F(x)$, $G$ increases in $y$, completing the proof of Claim 6.

Suppose there is $\lambda_0>0$ such that $\lambda_n\geq \lambda_0$ for all $n$. Then,
$$
D_n = G(c_n,1/(1-\lambda_n))\geq G(1,1/(1-\lambda_0)>0, \quad\text{for all $n$.}
$$
QED

Comment: @AsafShachar you're right. I should elaborate about this point. I will do it soon. The idea is to replace $a_n$ with its limit in the expression of $D_n$. By continuity, such a modification does not change whether it converges to zero or not.

Comment: @AsafShachar I've elaborated on "re-scaling." Note that the answer does not assume neither that $F$ is non-negative, nor that $c_n\to\infty$, rather just that it is bounded away from $a_n$.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I am still somewhat troubled tough. It seems to me that the most crucial non-trivial step is in passing from Lemma 3 to Lemma 4 (from $a_n$ to $\lim a_n$). I understand why $\liminf\lambda(a_n,c_n,b_n)=\liminf\lambda(\lim a_n,c_n,b_n)$ (because the difference between the 'lambdas' tend to zero.) However, I don't see why $\limsup D_f(a_n,c_n,b_n)= \limsup D_f(\lim a_n,c_n,b_n)$. I think it reduces to $\lim_{n \to \infty }( \lambda(a_n,c_n,b_n)-\lambda(\lim a_n,c_n,b_n))F(b_n)=0, $ but I don't see why this limit should be zero.

Comment: I have edited the question to make my misunderstanding clear. Thanks.

Comment: @AsafShachar, you're right. I've corrected the reduction from Lemma 3 to Lemma 4. Instead of using the continuity of $D_f$ in $a$, I now use monotonicity.